# Returning a python generator for timing analysis

Tags: python, profiling, generator

I wrote a snippet that uses generators to return the elapsed time since the last time it has been called.

```
def time_gen(start_time):
    start = start_time
    while True:
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        start = time.time()
        yield elapsed

def test():
    a = time_gen(time.time())
    for i in range(4):
        time.sleep(1) 
        print(a.next()) #prints about 1 second
```

It seems to work well. But I don't like how the user needs to pass in the start time. Is there a way to write a function that returns a generator with the start time already passed as a parameter?

```
#Broken Code
def time_closure():
    def time_gen(start_time):
        start = start_time
        while True:
            elapsed = time.time() - start
            start = time.time()
            yield elapsed

    a = time_gen(time.time())
    return a

#Usage of Broken Code
a = time_closure()
a.next()
```

Comment: Why do you say your second code snippet is broken?

Comment: Oh you are right. It does work. There was an issue with my repl. When I pasted it in to ipython it complained about the return. I thought this was because I didn't understand generators, but it was actually just a whitespace error. For anyone who has the same problem, use the %paste macro in ipython.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to pass start time to the generator. You can just do `start = time.time()` in its first line, and leave the rest as it is

Comment: That causes `start` to be computed on the first `next` call, rather than when the generator is created.